# What is name of this Captain in War of 1812?

Tags: palaeography, pension-records, war-of-1812

In [this pension file record on Fold](https://www.fold3.com/image/314142415), I have a commander whose name I cannot make out:

[image]

I've transcribed the page as follows:

> State of South Carolina, Pickens District } On this the Eighth Day of March 1859 personally appeared before me Thomas Dillard a Magistrate within and for the State and District Mrs Cuzzy Hill a resident of the State and District aforesaid Aged 58 years who being duly sworn according to Law  declares that she is the widow of Abel Hill Deceased who was a Private in the Company Commanded by Captain ?Cameron? in the Regiment not Recollected of South Carolina Volunteers in the war with Great Britain declared by the United States on the 18<sup>th</sup> Day of June A D 1812 — and that her said Husband the aforesaid Abell Hill died at his residence in the State and District aforesaid on the 10<sup>th</sup> Day of January A D 1828 and that she has remained a widow ever since his Death and is now a resident at this time. She further states that she has been drawing a pension under the act of February 3<sup>rd</sup> 1853 for the term of five years from the First day of February 1854 and terminating on the first day of February 1859 at the rate of Three Dollars and fifty cents fee ?ammeu? and that her certificate of Pension is numbered no 3885 and the same has been surrendered. She makes this declaration for the Purpose of

The captain's name, W<sup>m</sup> ?Cammous?, also [appears here](https://www.fold3.com/image/314142424) by a different writer:

[image]

Can anyone make out the name of the Captain circled?  What about the word near the end ?ammeu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the Captain would appear to be "**Cannon**" in the first image (appearing more legibly in  "Captain Wm Cannons Company" in the second).

The phrase at the end is "**per annum**" (compare the "p" in "per" with the "p" in "Captain" in your first image)

[image: snippet view of text]

---

I did a quick search for `"South Carolina Volunteers" "1812"`, and found this [list](http://freepages.rootsweb.com/~york/military/1812/Nashs.html) of *Nash's Regiment SC Volunteers* on Rootsweb.  The list includes both a *Private Abel Hill* and a *Captain William Cannon*, and so might also be of interest to you.